# How to group Component sidebar menu, or add headings?

Tags: component, custom-component, sidebar

In my custom component, I have a sidebar with several entries. These are added using `JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(...)`, as described in [Joomla Documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlSidebar.html).

Most of these sidebar menu items will rarely be used by users. I want to group the different sidebar items. Or maybe add a menu heading in between some of them.

Is this at all possible? I can't find any info on this.

Any input is most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JHtmlSidebar` is pretty simple and doesn't support headings/separators or anything like that. But you can fake them by adding the required HTML to the language string used as a name for the entry and omitting the link.

The language string:

```
COM_MYCOMPONENT_SUBMENU_HEADING="<h3>My Heading</h3>"
COM_MYCOMPONENT_SUBMENU_SEPARATOR="<span class=\"class-for-separator\"></span>"
```

The `addEntry()` calls:

```
JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
    JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_SUBMENU_HEADING')
);

JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
    JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_SUBMENU_SEPARATOR')
);
```

If you want more control over the sidebar layout, you can create an override of `joomla.sidebars.submenu` layout specifically for your component.

Finally, you don't even have to use `JHtmlSidebar` to create a sidebar for your component.

Comment: Thanks @Sharky! That works perfectly. :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. How would you add the sidebar without using `JHtmlSidebar`?

Comment: Any way you want. It's just a list of links.